# Unprivileged video application crashing Cinnamon

Tags: linux, graphics-card, crash, intel-graphics, cinnamon

I am having a long term problem, which I am unable to solve. I am using Dell i7 laptop running Debian Linux with Cinnamon and Intel GPU.

I am a heavy Zoom.us (video conferencing) application user and it keeps crashing my laptop sometime after Zoom session starts (the Windows manager freezes). I am able to open an alternative shell (Alt-Ctrl-F1), but killing Cinnamon / Zoom is not helping (switching back to F7 displays the same freezed screen).

Zoom obviously buggy, but still it is does not suppose to crash the system.

(BTW - Zoom support is not helping too much, after months of ping-pongs)

`$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: my-laptop Kernel: 4.9.0-6-amd64 x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 6.3.0)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.2.7 (Gtk 3.22.11-1) Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Dell product: Latitude E5470
           Mobo: Dell model: 06DNG5 v: A00 UEFI: Dell v: 1.17.3 date: 08/17/2017
Battery    BAT0: charge: 56.0 Wh 80.2% condition: 69.8/81.6 Wh (86%)
           model: Samsung SDI DELL TXF9M62 status: Charging
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-6820HQ (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 21696
           clock speeds: max: 3600 MHz 1: 799 MHz 2: 799 MHz 3: 799 MHz 4: 799 MHz 5: 799 MHz 6: 799 MHz
           7: 799 MHz 8: 799 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics 530 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.2 drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.02hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-H HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.9.0-6-amd64
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k bus-ID: 00:1f.6
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 01:00.0
           IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (Used Error!)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 500.1GB
           ID-2: /dev/mmcblk0 model: N/A size: 127.9GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 23G used: 9.9G (46%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1
           ID-2: /boot size: 237M used: 87M (39%) fs: ext2 dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-3: /var size: 9.2G used: 7.0G (81%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-2
           ID-4: /tmp size: 1.8G used: 7.8M (1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-4
           ID-5: /home size: 408G used: 342G (89%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-5
           ID-6: swap-1 size: 17.07GB used: 0.34GB (2%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-3
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 52.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 313 Uptime: 2 days Memory: 6045.7/15819.6MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 6.3.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.121) inxi: 2.3.5`

Any ideas on how to find our the problem? 
Tnx

Comment: Possible workaround: run the app in a VM... at least the main OS should not crash. See https://jtreminio.com/2012/07/setting-up-a-debian-vm-step-by-step/

Comment: Actually I was thinking of maybe running a Windows based app with Wine. Yet I am not sure Wine supports webcam/mic hardware dependencies..... Having a dedicated VM is a too high overhead....